# Java: Method overriding and typecast

Tags: java

Let's suppose that there's a class called Question, and I want to override the equals method there. I want to make it so that two of these objects are the same if the attribute 'number' is the same in both of them.

Now, why do I have to make the typecast "(Question)o", if I already checked with the if condition if 'o' is an instance of Question?

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof Question) {
        return ((Question) o).number == number;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Java isn't smart enough. I believe Swift can do this, for example.

Comment: Yeah, not mentioning that this kind of inference is not as easy as it seems. Since `o` is not final, its value could be change to a different instance inside the if block, for example

Comment: we have A,B,C they are 3 class, B and C extends A, B have an variable named color, C have an variable names engine, instanceOf will return true for (B instanceOf A, C instanceOf A ) but we have to cast to make sure that the variable we are using is B not C, it's not a cast is like a promise that my instance that i'm working with is an B not an C

Comment: Kotlin would be able to work out that o is a Question inside the if statement, I think they call it smart casting.  At runtime the object o may or may not be a Question, but as far as the equals method is concerned it is going to consider o as an Object, the instanceof call is just a check of one type against  an expected type.  If the runtime type of o matches you still need to up-cast to Question to be able to use the methods of Question.

Comment: Eclipse autocomplete will offer `Question` members inside the `if` and will automatically insert the cast.

Comment: @MrD I think you mean `return o instanceof Question && ((Question)o).number == number;`.

Comment: @shmosel yes, exactly

Answer (score 2):

The instanceof operator simply does a check on the object `o` to see if it is an instance of `Question`. It doesn't do any mutation of state or type of the `o` since we have already designated it as an `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You give `Object o` parameter in the following:

```
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
```

JVM checks if `o` is an instance of `Question`, just to proceed to the next line.

```
if(o instanceof Question) {
```

But when it comes to the next line, you still have declared type as `Object`,so if number is an attribute of the `Question` class, the compiler will catch it as an error.

```
  return ((Question) o).number == number;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To learn more about declared type, [click here.](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/dispatch.html)